# Facebook Integration Scope Permission

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, facebook

Scopes required :- manage_pages & publish_pages
Review required.
Tried Twice thrice uploaded screen cast and wrote steps.
Submitted for review.

Every time rejected. I don't have permission to access manage_pages & publish_pages then how can i show reviewer that it will use this two permission and how it will make posting on facebook page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test the application with administrator. Check your developers.facebook.com you will have roles tab.
In that roles tab whoever is in the Admin role will be having all permission default.
perform the Integration with facebook and try to use that admin's ID for asking permission with post sharing on facebook page.